# Unexpected result from this code

Tags: c#, c#-2.0, c#-to-vb.net

I have an object declared as:

```
private string SourceProgram;
```

Basically i am trying to parse some stuff using the code below:

```
 private void LabelScan(System.IO.BinaryWriter OutputFile, bool IsLabelScan)
        {

            if (char.IsLetter(SourceProgram[CurrentNdx]))
            {
               if (IsLabelScan) LabelTable.Add(GetLabelName(), AsLength);
                while (SourceProgram[CurrentNdx] != '\n')
                    CurrentNdx++;
                CurrentNdx++;
                return;
            }
            EatWhiteSpaces();
            ReadMneumonic(OutputFile, IsLabelScan);
        }
```

However i get an error on execution:

```
-       SourceProgram[CurrentNdx]   
'SourceProgram[CurrentNdx]' threw an exception of 
type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException'  char {System.IndexOutOfRangeException}

-       base    {"Index was outside the bounds of the array."}
    System.SystemException {System.IndexOutOfRangeException}
```

And the Value of `CurrentNdx` is 46.

What has gone wrong. Is the string variable `SourceProgram` of `length < 46` ?

If yes, how to fix this code?

Comment: where do you reset `CurrentNdx`? And yes - the string seems to have less than 47 characters.

Comment: Shouldn't the question "is the string variable ... < 46?" be something you should be able to see in the debugger?

Comment: @ Lasse V. Karlsen:: isn't it obvious its out of range.
@BrokenGlass:: I cant reset CurrentNdx since im using it to read into a file and it needs to keep getting incremented.

Comment: @user: ok - where do you *add* to the string then? If it's a fixed string check the answers below - you might not have a `\n`

Comment: Is there a way to make SourceProgram larger... i mean dynamically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this error suggests that SourceProgram has less than 47 characters.  That's pretty much all we can tell you though without seeing the contents of SourceProgram.

Answer (score 0):

The code seems to look for a new line character in the string SourceProgram. Maybe SourceProgram doesn't contain a \n?

Surely it would be better to use `int position = SourceProgram.indexOf("\n")` to find the position of the \n

Also, you don't appear to be resetting CurrentNdx to zero in this code, which would likely be required elsewhere

Comment: @user667389 Then why not use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5xkyx09y.aspx This indexOf specifies the first character to search from. Then this could be used to update the CurrentNdx?

Answer (score 0):

```
while (SourceProgram[CurrentNdx] != '\n')
                    CurrentNdx++;
```

maybe your SourceProgram string doesn't contain a newline, or the function is called after CurrentNdx is beyond any newlines in the string.